# How to extract text in order and use as input in bash script

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I am new here as well as bash script. Is it possible create a script to extract text in order to use as input for another program.
My input file ($in_put) is in this format. The samples are pair-ends files from different sequencing runs:
    `sample_1    a    b`
    `sample_2    c    d`
    `sample_3    e    f`
The program I am trying to use is Trimmomatic. I tried for in range because thats the only loop that I know in bash which could run in order. Here is what I did:
`smpl_no=3`
`test_val=$(for (( b=1; b<=$smpl_no; b++)); do grep ple_$b $in_put | awk '{print $2, $3}'; done)`
However, where I check with `echo $test_val`, it gives me `a b c d e f` all together. I would like to extract the value in pair as `a b`, `c d` and `d e` and turn them into variable for Trimmomatic.

In the future my have more sample as the input as well. What is the best way to approach this?

Comment: Can't you call your "another program" inside the loop?

Comment: @Giang Le: Could you please put more information into your post, like sample Input and expected output, it will be easy for us to help you in same then.

Comment: Sample input are paired end fastq files from different runs and the program is Trimmomatic. I am trying to create a script to read the name of the pair-end file and run them in order as the input file.

Comment: It looks like you want arrays instead of test_val=$(...). Use the for, and push each value to an array on each iteration.

Comment: The best option is definitely the `GNU parallel` tool, but I'm not sure what exactly you want to run to write the code..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fill more vars with one `read` call:

```
while read -r sample param1 param2; do
   echo "Sample ${sample}"
   echo "Calling Trimmomatic ${param1} ${param2}"
   trimmomatic "${param1}" "${param2}"
done < "${in_put}"
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used Trimmomatic, but based on [this doc page](http://www.usadellab.org/cms/?page=trimmomatic), I think you need to list each of `a` through `f` as a separate parameter, right?

```
smpl_no=3
elems=()   # make an array
for(( b=0; b<$smpl_no; ++b)); do   # arrays start at 0

   read -r _ elem1 elem2 < <(grep ple_$b $in_put)
       # Get, e.g., "a" and "b" into $elem1 and $elem2
   elems+=("$elem1" "$elem2")
       # Save them in an array

done

java -jar trimmomatic-0.35.jar PE -phred33 "${elems[@]}" ILLUMINACLIP ... <whatever else>
    # each element as a separate parameter ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

If you want just the pairs, each pair can be had as `"${elems[$idx]}"` and `"${elems[$idx + 1]}"` for `idx`=0, 2, 4, ... .